# Why does my jsfiddle work but not my web site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsfiddle

I'm not sure what im missing here

I have the following JS fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/thetylercox/eeMva/3/

And the site:

http://soldbybillcox.com/treasure/demo1.html

I'm not sure what I am missing but my website does not work.

Comment: Make sure you don't have a copy paste error, more than likely you copied an extra character at the bottom.

Comment: i fixed this see here http://soldbybillcox.com/treasure/demo1.html its still not like the js fiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

â€‹ from copying and pasting from fiddle

Answer (score 4):

On the **line 68** you have illegial symbols right after a closing bracket `}`.

[image]

Remove it and the code should work.

Comment: thats not in my code i have Dream weaver up it looks like }</script>

Comment: http://soldbybillcox.com/treasure/demo1.html

Comment: @tman The same line still has some invalid invisible symbol. I believe it is hidden in spaces of identation or between the visible symbols.

Answer (score 4):

Just before your closing `</script>` tag, you've got an illegal character.
Try right-clicking and 'view-source' in Chrome. You'll see it. Line #68.

Comment: thats not in my code i have Dream weaver up it looks like }</script>

Comment: @tman - It happens when you copy/paste from jsFiddle. If you just remove the 'whitespace' that you see, it'll remove the character. Dreamweaver will just show it as whitespace, not the actual character(s).

Comment: @ahren "*Dreamweaver will just show it as whitespace, not the actual character(s)*"; actually: it aren't (actual) characters ;-) They are 'shown' because the page is served with a `Content-Type: text/html` as opposed to, say, `Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf8`. Because of this, the `ISO-8859-1` encoding is used and it can't handle those bytes. See [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: @RobIII - thanks for the info ;-) always learning!

Comment: wow ok well i fixed it here but it still doesnt work http://soldbybillcox.com/treasure/demo1.html

Comment: Again: check your console! (CTRL+Shift+j in chrome, F12 in Internet explorer, etc...). And [follow my advice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11551123/215042). Just retype the few damn chars. See [here](http://i.imgur.com/j1mbx.png) and [here](http://i.imgur.com/ziBdy.png)

Answer (score 2):

Open up your console, it says: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL, demo.php:68`

```
    ...
    var total1 = document.getElementById("total1").value = total;

}â€‹
```

These might be caused by a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) if you're using different files/includes to generate the output. Otherwise, it might just be some copy/paste error. Just remove the `}â€‹</script>` to make sure the 'invisible' chars are gone between `}` and `<` and then type `}</script>` again and be done with it.

Comment: i fixed this see here it still does not behave as the js fiddle does http://soldbybillcox.com/treasure/demo1.html

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work just fine, except you have a random trio of symbols at the end of your `<script>`, so remove those and it should be just fine.

Comment: i did this still no luck see here http://soldbybillcox.com/treasure/demo1.html