# why this jQuery works on jsfiddle.net and not work on my website?

Tags: jquery, css, menu, fade, jsfiddle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does my jsfiddle work but not my web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551088/why-does-my-jsfiddle-work-but-not-my-web-site)

Hello. Sorry, I have a problem with an answer in another question; I mean this: http://jsfiddle.net/Mb6Nd/

I tried to use it on my site like this: and side.js is the jQuery code on http://jsfiddle.net/Mb6Nd/ and it didnt work for me. Please help me.

Thank you

```
 <header>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="side.js"></script>
 </header>
    <style>
    ul li {background-color: #cecece;}
    </style>

    <ul id="mainmenu">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
    </ul>
    ​
```

Comment: When your question is downvoted, it's a sign that it needs improvement, not a sign that you need to repost. Read the [faq], and work on improving your question.

Answer (score 2):

Your markup is *invalid*, style tags should be within head tag not after *header* tags, also you should first load jQuery in order use jQuery methods and properties.

```
<html>
   <head>
       <script type="text/javascript" src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="side.js"></script>
       <style>
         ul li {background-color: #cecece;}
       </style>
   </head>
   <body>
       <ul id="mainmenu">
          <li>item 1</li>
          <li>item 2</li>
          <li>item 3</li>
       </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i exactly do that but it dos not work :|
somebody said jsfiddle automaticly set some thing on windows.load
but he removed his comment and i dond understand :(

Comment: @user1647406 In your provided fiddle you have `$(document).ready()`, this should not be the issue. You should make sure that your scripts are loaded, if you are using firefox you can install firebug and it tells you whether scripts are loaded or your code has syntax errors or not.

Comment: my problem is just a color fader menu . can you help me make menus like http://jsfiddle.net/Mb6Nd/ ?? i just want a color fader menu

Comment: @user1647406 I have checked your page, there are redundant chars at the end of your slide.js file, remove this => `â€‹`

Comment: @user1647406 **Install** firefug, or use other debugging tools.

Answer (score 1):

It was possibly a file reference error

You are not including the jQuery file anywhere

Include

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

above the side.js

Comment: thank you for your attention . yes i use that like this :
`<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
 <script>
  google.load("jquery", "1.7");
  google.load("jqueryui", "1.8");
 </script>`

i dont understand this : 
or move your script tag below your elements
please explane for me .

Comment: Why are you loading 2 versions of jQuery.. Just load the latest version 1.8.0 .. Moving script tag below the lements makes sure your page loads faster so that all the elements are parsed before you hit the script files..

Comment: even when i use the latest jQuery it dos nor work on my website
'<html>
   <head>
       <script type="text/javascript" scr='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="side.js"></script>
       <style>
         ul li {background-color: #cecece;}
       </style>
   </head>
   <body>
       <ul id="mainmenu">
          <li>item 1</li>
          <li>item 2</li>
          <li>item 3</li>
       </ul>
   </body>
</html>'

Comment: look at this : http://shaweb.ir/test/
whats my wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong html tag , plus jsfiddle includes jquery but you dont seem to have included it. Include the jquery script

Comment: i included that 
look at this :
http://shaweb.ir/test/
what's my wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

does that say **$ not defined**? if yes, your jquery has not loaded, also see that your script gets loaded. Please install firebug on your system or if you have google chrome just press F12 to see the console and you would have a clearer picture.